# How to manage a filter on a website with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to get the data of a website which has a filter. The website is the following one: https://www.lequipe.fr/Basket/RES_NBA.html

I have a simply spider which collect all the information required but only for the date which is displayed.

I need to iterate the filter in order to collect the data of all the date available in the filter.

If someone can help i'll appreciate a lot.

My spider is like this:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import scrapy


class LequipeBotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Lequipe_bot'
allowed_domains = ['www.lequipe.fr/Basket/RES_NBA.html']
start_urls = ['http://www.lequipe.fr/Basket/RES_NBA.html']
#location of csv file
custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT' : "csv",
    'FEED_URI' : 'tmp/lequipe2.csv'
}

def parse(self, response):
    #Extracting the content using css selectors
    #recap = response.css(".equipeDom a::text,div.score span.score--chiffre::text,.equipeExt a::text").extract()
    recap=response.css(".equipeDom a::text,div.score span.score--chiffre::text,.equipeExt a::text,div.equipeDom span.nba--ranking::text,div.equipeExt span.nba--ranking::text").extract()

    #Give the extracted content row wise
    for x in range(0,(len(recap))/6):
        #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
        scraped_info = {
            'equipe_dom' : recap[1+6*x],
            'score_dom' : recap[2+6*x],
            'score_ext' : recap[3+6*x],
            'equipe_ext' : recap[4+6*x],
            'classement_dom' : recap[0+6*x],
            'classement_ext' : recap[5+6*x],

        }

        #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
        yield scraped_info
```

So, how can i iterate the scraping of all pages with the solution of @furas

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have all dates in `class=filtrecalendrier` and every date has link to page with details. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You have all dates in `select` widget with `class=filtrecalendrier`.
And there are urls to pages with details

```
for x in response.xpath('//*[@class="filtrecalendrier"]/option/@value'): 
    print(x.extract())
```

Result

```
/Basket/BasketResultat22420.html
/Basket/BasketResultat22421.html
/Basket/BasketResultat22422.html
...
```

Now you have to join it with `https://www.lequipe.fr/`

```
response.urljoin('/Basket/BasketResultat22420.html')

# https://www.lequipe.fr/Basket/BasketResultat22420.html
```

and you can load page to get details

---

**EDIT:** working code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761077/1832058
#

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['www.lequipe.fr']

    start_urls = ['http://www.lequipe.fr/Basket/RES_NBA.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="filtrecalendrier"]/option'): 

            date = item.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
            url = item.xpath('./@value').extract_first()

            url = response.urljoin(url)

            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_items, meta={'date': date})


    def parse_items(self, response):
        rows = response.css('.ligne.bb-color')

        for row in rows:

            score = row.css('.score span::text').extract()
            if len(score) < 2:
                score = ['', '']

            item = {
                'date': response.meta['date'],
                'equipe_dom': row.css('.equipeDom a::text').extract_first(),
                'score_dom':  score[0],
                'score_ext':  score[1],
                'equipe_ext': row.css('.equipeExt a::text').extract_first(),
                'classement_dom': row.css('.equipeDom a span::text').extract_first(),
                'classement_ext': row.css('.equipeExt a span::text').extract_first(),
            }

            #print(item)

            yield item

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Furas, i'm a real begginer at scrapy so nothing is obvious for me ;) I will try your solution and see how  can i iterate it in my spider. Again, thanks you a lot.

Comment: Thanks you so much furas. I was far away from this but now i'm back and i will try your code. We keep in touch.